# How do Intel HD Graphics from 2010 processors compare to current low level graphics cards?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, performance, integrated-graphics

This question is similar to [this](https://superuser.com/q/59882/36601), but here I'm asking about [Intel HD Graphics integrated into 2010 processors](http://www.intel.com/technology/graphics/intelhd.htm) in general and graphics integrated into [Atom N550](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=50154) in particular.

A site with reviews would be good.

And yes, I know that this is a Google question, but at the moment, I can't find any relevant reviews using Internet searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tom's hardware has the best comparison information that I have found.  From [this table](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/gaming-graphics-radeon-hd-6870-radeon-hd-6850,2782-7.html) it would appear the current generation Intel HD integrated graphics are about equal to the lowest end discrete ATI & nVidia cards of 3 generations ago (nVidia 6600 or ATI X1400).

AndrejaKo's link does not specify which Intel integrated graphics processor the N550 uses.  My recollection of the Atom N550 announcement is that it has Intel GMA 3150 graphics.  That is 4 steps slower than the Intel HD graphics (nVidia FX 5200 or ATI 9200).

This all sounds disappointingly slow until you consider that unless you are playing 3D games or doing CAD or other "professional" 3D work the Intel integrated GPU is more than adequate.  The Intel HD on the Core i5-6x1 chips is even certified for use by [AutoCAD](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/hc?siteID=123112&id=6711853&linkID=9240618&is_results=1&card_sel=0&manufac=32902&card=0&cert=1&d_stat=1&d_stat=2&d_stat=3&prod=AutoCAD-R17.2&prod=AutoCAD-R18.0&prod=AutoCAD-R18.1&os=1&os=512&os=256&os=2048&os=4096&os=8192&os=1073741824&os=536870912).